# Very weird issue with AuthorizationExecuteWithPriveleges in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, bash, terminal

I'm using AuthorizationExecuteWithPriveleges to execute bash commands from my App with admin privilege. I have found really weird issue. Here what I'm using

```
    FILE *pipe=nil;
    OSStatus err;
    AuthorizationRef authorizationRef;
    char *command= "/bin/chmod";
  
    
    char *args[] = {"644","folderPath", nil};

   if(err!=0)
    {
                                err = AuthorizationCreate(nil,
                                       kAuthorizationEmptyEnvironment,
                                       kAuthorizationFlagDefaults,
                                       &authorizationRef);
    }
    NSLog(@"test");
    err = AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges(authorizationRef,
                                             command,
                                             kAuthorizationFlagDefaults,
                                             args,
                                             &pipe);
```

After calling this function about 40 times, it's starting respond very slowly. And after it is will just die,and freeze application, and I have no idea what is happening to this.It doesn't show the log "test", and doesn't do anything, after calling about 40 times.
**It doesn't matter what Bash command or what arguments you are using. It still does the same thing.** What is wrong with this ? The reason I'm using this, because my App needs to run on 10.5 as well.

Please if someone have idea, what can I do. I really appreciate it. I need ASAP. Thanks

Comment: Maybe consider calling `AuthorizationFree`? Or not re-creating authorization?

Comment: I tried it too. But actually I don't need re-creating authorization. It just must be authorized once. But I tried it , won't help..VERy VERY strange issue.

Comment: truss or strace or ? for OSx. Good luck.

Comment: You are using an uninitialized variable `err`. What if it's value is 0 by accident. Perhaps that's whats happening when your code hangs.

Comment: if it is 0 , it means Authorization succesful.. I tried to to initialize , it won't help

Comment: err having not initial value; I would set err so that your if condition is satisfied, or change your if so that it will create the authorization. I would declare AuthorizationRef * authorizationRef; and would remove the & from this parameter when calling AuthorizationCreate(). I wonder whether you should use NSString instead of char * for your command and args variables, and if you do then prefix your strings with @.

Comment: AuthoriztionRef is already a reference type so your declaration is fine; forget what I said about the * and & in my earlier comment. However, initialize authorizationRef = NULL and you need to check if authorizationRef != NULL and err == success before calling method ExecuteWithPrivileges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looked at this a bit more, and cooked up the following example, presented without warranty, but which works for me for thousands of invocations of AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges without issue:

```
void DoOtherStuff(AuthorizationRef auth, char* path);

void DoStuff(char* path)
{
    AuthorizationItem foo;
    foo.name = kAuthorizationRightExecute;
    foo.value = NULL;
    foo.valueLength = 0;
    foo.flags = 0;

    AuthorizationRights rights;
    rights.count = 1;
    rights.items = &foo;

    AuthorizationRef authorizationRef;
    OSStatus err = errAuthorizationSuccess;

    if (errAuthorizationSuccess != (err = AuthorizationCreate(NULL,  kAuthorizationEmptyEnvironment, kAuthorizationFlagDefaults, &authorizationRef)))    
    {
        NSLog(@"Error on AuthorizationCreate: %lu", (long)err);
        return;
    }

    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
    {
        NSLog(@"Doing run: %lu", (long)i+1);
        DoOtherStuff(authorizationRef, "/tmp/foo");
    }

    if (errAuthorizationSuccess != (err = AuthorizationFree(authorizationRef, kAuthorizationFlagDefaults)))
    {
        NSLog(@"Error on AuthorizationFree: %lu", (long)err);
        return;
    }
}

void DoOtherStuff(AuthorizationRef authorizationRef, char* path)
{    
    OSStatus err = errAuthorizationSuccess;
    FILE *pipe = NULL;
    @try
    {
        char *args[] = {"644", path, NULL};
        if (errAuthorizationSuccess != (err = AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges(authorizationRef,
                                                 "/bin/chmod", kAuthorizationFlagDefaults, args, &pipe)))
        {
            NSLog(@"Error on AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges: %lu", (long)err);
            return;
        }

        int stat;
        wait(&stat);

        NSLog(@"Success! Child Process Died!");
    }
    @finally 
    {        
        if (pipe)
            fclose(pipe);
    }
}
```

What Chris Suter said is dead on. What happens when you call AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges is that it fork()s your process and then exec()s the requested process (chmod in this case) from the child process. The child process won't be reaped until someone calls wait(), but that's hard because we don't get the PID of the child out of AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges (it would have been returned by fork()). As he said, if you're sure there aren't other threads spawning processes at the same time (i.e. your thread is the only one creating child processes), then you can just call the non-PID specific version of wait() like I do in this example.

If you don't call wait() then what happens is you accumulate these zombie child processes that are all waiting to be reaped.  Eventually the OS says "no more."

I feel kinda bad posting this, since it's just a retread of what Chris Suter said; I've upvoted his answer.

For completeness, here's a reworked version of that example that achieves the goal by ignoring SIGCHLD instead of calling wait. It also is presented without warranty, but works for me.

```
void DoOtherStuff(AuthorizationRef auth, char* path);

void DoStuff(char* path)
{
    AuthorizationItem foo;
    foo.name = kAuthorizationRightExecute;
    foo.value = NULL;
    foo.valueLength = 0;
    foo.flags = 0;

    AuthorizationRights rights;
    rights.count = 1;
    rights.items = &foo;

    AuthorizationRef authorizationRef;
    OSStatus err = errAuthorizationSuccess;

    struct sigaction oldAction;
    struct sigaction newAction;

    newAction.__sigaction_u.__sa_handler = SIG_IGN;
    newAction.sa_mask = 0;
    newAction.sa_flags = 0;

    if(0 != sigaction(SIGCHLD, &newAction, &oldAction))
    {
        NSLog(@"Couldn't ignore SIGCHLD");
        return;
    }

    @try
    {
        if (errAuthorizationSuccess != (err = AuthorizationCreate(NULL,  kAuthorizationEmptyEnvironment, kAuthorizationFlagDefaults, &authorizationRef)))    
        {
            NSLog(@"Error on AuthorizationCreate: %lu", (long)err);
            return;
        }

        for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            NSLog(@"Doing run: %lu", (long)i+1);
            DoOtherStuff(authorizationRef, "/tmp/foo");
        }

        if (errAuthorizationSuccess != (err = AuthorizationFree(authorizationRef, kAuthorizationFlagDefaults)))
        {
            NSLog(@"Error on AuthorizationFree: %lu", (long)err);
            return;
        }
    }
    @finally 
    {
        const struct sigaction cOldAction = oldAction;
        if(0 != sigaction(SIGCHLD, &cOldAction, NULL))
        {
            NSLog(@"Couldn't restore the handler for SIGCHLD");
            return;
        }

    }
}

void DoOtherStuff(AuthorizationRef authorizationRef, char* path)
{ 
    OSStatus err = errAuthorizationSuccess;
    FILE *pipe = NULL;
    @try
    {
        char *args[] = {"644", path, NULL};
        if (errAuthorizationSuccess != (err = AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges(authorizationRef,
                                                 "/bin/chmod", kAuthorizationFlagDefaults, args, &pipe)))
        {
            NSLog(@"Error on AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges: %lu", (long)err);
            return;
        }

        NSLog(@"Success!");
    }
    @finally 
    {        
        if (pipe)
            fclose(pipe);
    }
}
```

Comment: Looking at his code and yours that works, you don't think that it's at least in part due to the fact that his code probably skips the AuthorizationCreate call? I ask, because I don't have a system to test at the moment.

Comment: That could certainly be, but I also saw the strange symptoms he reported, and there's a pretty good explanation for them, so...

Answer (score 2):

What you’re trying to do is not a good idea.

I would guess that you have a bug else where in your code, perhaps in the monitoring of the pipe. We need to see the rest of your code.

If you do pursue this approach, you will need to take care and make sure that you clean up zombie processes which can be awkward when using AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges because you don’t get the child process ID. You’ll either need to ignore `SIGCHLD`, or if you can be certain there are no other threads that are doing things with processes at the same time, you can just issue a call to `wait`.

You’ve also got to make sure you clean up the pipe as otherwise you’ll run out of file descriptors.

The system is far less forgiving about you leaking file descriptors or processes than it is about leaking memory.

The correct approach for your problem is probably to write a helper tool and then communicate with your helper tool asking it to perform privileged operations on your behalf. That way you’ll only be running your helper tool once. You should be able to read more about this in Apple’s documentation.

Comment: Thanks. I'm aware of Better Authorization sample in Apple doc. But it won't work on 10.5. About zombies, and bugs in code. I tried to run it separately in new project. And call same function many times, it will do the same. I'm not using pipe, it's nil. So the pipe is not reason as well. Thanks

Comment: As far as I know Better Authorization Sample works fine on 10.5 unless there’s a bug that I’m not aware of. If it doesn’t work, you can revert to using a setuid helper tool (which is what all our stuff does, for legacy reasons).

Answer (score 1):

You should initialize err (due to the first IF statement), because it's no guaranteed to be 0. However, it probably is, so you are skipping AuthorizationCreate, so the authorized session isn't created.

Basically you are passing authorizationRef uninitialized to AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges which might be a problem.

Plus like others, I would put AuthorizationFree(authorizationRef,kAuthorizationFlagDefaults); at the end as well when you do use AuthorizationCreate to free the memory.

Also it's worth noting that AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges is deprecated as of OS X v10.7, but I think you know that since you said you are trying to run on 10.5

EDIT: You might want to check the status of err too after running AuthorizationCreate

```
if ( err != errAuthorizationSuccess ) {
  return;
}
```

... you should check err after AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think I might know what's going on here: Try handling the pipe correctly (i.e. don't pass NULL, and make sure you close it). Weird stuff like this also happens with NSTask if you fail to give it a STDIN pipe. [This page](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSTask) over at cocoadev.com explains:

> An NSTask will break Xcode's debug log entirely if you execute
>   ANYTHING related with sh or bash (including scripts). printf, NSLog;
>   all will cease to function as soon as the task has been launched. Even
>   things like right clicking on an object in the debugger will yield
>   nothing (straight GDB still prints though). ... I figured out that the
>   problem lies with standard input, of all things. A quick fix for this
>   would be to set your standard input up to something random, like a
>   pipe, and do nothing with it.

This stumped me for hours and hours (albiet with NSTask and not AS). I would be surprised if the odd behavior you're seeing isn't related. Make sure you're not passing NULL, and then make sure that you're cleaning up the file handle that AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges creates for you, by calling fclose, etc.

I'm not 100% sure, but the "NSLog stopped working" symptom caught my eye.

Comment: I tried to handle PIPE like you said. But still the same issue. It won't help.. But thanks for the post about NSTask was very usefull.